# Adjusting screen brightness in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: screen, system-settings

How can I modify the screen brightness in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ? In the Systems Settings -> Brightness & Lock screen, all I see are options related to the screen saver, but nothing for changing the current screen brightness. Shouldn't there be a scroll bar for brightness level in this window ?

[image]

Comment: You can find it in System Settings -> "Power"

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to adjust screen brightness in ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540911/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue... When this happened I had booted Ubuntu in recovery mode. Some options are not available in recovery mode, such as adjusting screen brightness and using multiple monitors.

When I booted back in normal mode, the screen brightness adjustment settings were available.