# How to link the system event brightness up/down to the correct brightness file

Tags: 14.04, laptop, brightness, asus, backlight

I have a ASUS UL30VT and just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The screen brightness was at level 0.

**Attempt 1:** so I navigated to find the screen brightness slider under System Settings>Brightness&Lock. Moving the slider did not affect the screen brightness.

**Attempt 2:** I used the hotkey on my keyboard <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> for brightness up and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for brightness down. The symbol at the top right of the screen showing that the brightness changes shows, but the screen brightness never changed.

**Attempt3:** I tried the answer in this askubuntu question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540911/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-14-04) and it learned me the following. Running `ls` in `/sys/class/backlight/` yields

```
asus_laptop
intel_backlight
```

so apparently i have duplicate settings. Moving the slider in System Settings>Brightness&Lock adjusts the values in `asus_baklight\brightness`. Manually editing the file `intel_backlight\brightness` makes the screen changed, just as i hope.

So how do I make the system event of changing screen brightness link to the correct brightness file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution that may work for you

Edit your grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change the line line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

then save and exit. Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot your PC

This should add its own backlight control as intel_backlight, adding this line forces acpi to use the Intel backlight.

If this doesn't work you can try the information in [Brightness Adjustment Fatal Freeze + Odd boot screen start up error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192471)

this talks about creating an entry in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
that looks something like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"    "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Okay. Ive tried solution 1 above. Adding the said arguments in the grub file didnt help. Ill turn to solution 2 now!

Comment: SOLUTION 2 WORKS !!! HOOORAY! Great thank you! :)