# Adjusting brightness to my laptop

Tags: 14.04, dell, brightness

I try through System Settings to change the brightness of my screen, but nothing happens.
I also tried to follow this answer [How to adjust screen brightness in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540911/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-14-04). But I think that the problem is that I use an NVIDIA GEFORCE for grpghics.

Comment: Which answer did you try  from "how to adjust screen brightness in ubuntu 14.04?."

Comment: try the second answer, the one with "xrandr" command in this link. If it works let me know in the commnets section.I can write you a script then.  [the link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Comment: Yes it helped, now I can change it through terminal. But there is still a problem, no matter if I try to change it through System setting or with the fn button it still doesn't change.
thank you btw