# Brightness key on keyboard not working

Tags: 16.04

So I have seen this a few times but haven't seen a solution. I also don't know if it is computer hardware related problem or not.

My brightness keys ( <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd>) to set the brightness in Ubuntu 16.04 does nothing, I have a HP Pavillion Laptop computer. Can anyone help me fix this. I have seen a "sort of solution" downloading an application called "Brightness Controller" but that is not a real solution for me.

Please help me with this if you can.. Thanks W

When running `acpi_listen` command in the terminal I get the following output:

```
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000 
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000 
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything after installing the above

Comment: nothing happening with {xbacklight -dec 20} .. the folder got "Intel Backlight" " acpi_video0" "acpi_video1" forlders inside

Comment: I am finding it hard to change these settings.. please explain a bit more

Comment: @Sneetsher I have found the following [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540911/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness-in-ubuntu-14-04) and it seems to work. It is a manual approach.

Comment: its a bit of a pain but thanks for you help..I'll stick with it for now. Thanks once again.                                                                                                 This script work great , I modified it slightly to fit my system`#!/bin/mksh
printf " \n Entering file to change brightness in 3 seconds\n remember - no new line after number.  ";
sleep 3;
sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `acpi_listen` in the terminal, to test if the key event received by the system. Then press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> & <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. Below an output example:

   ```
    # acpi_listen 
     PNP0C14:00 000000d0 00000000
    video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
     PNP0C14:00 000000d0 00000000
    video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
   ```
2. See if you can control backlight using

   ```
    sudo apt-get install xbacklight
        xbacklight -inc 20
        xbacklight -dec 20
   ```

   Another try at lower level

   ```
    # ls -l /sys/class/backlight/
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 10 13:56 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight

    # ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
    total 0
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 14:28 actual_brightness
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 14:28 bl_power
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 15:19 brightness
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 14:28 device -> ../../card0-LVDS-1
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 14:28 max_brightness
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 10 14:28 power
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 14:28 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
    -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 14:28 type
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 14:28 uevent

    # echo 3600 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```
3. Setup an ACPI script as explained in [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/)

   **`/etc/acpi/events/intel-backlight`**

   ```
    event=video/brightness*
    action=/etc/acpi/intel-backlight.sh
   ```

   **`/etc/acpi/intel-backlight.sh`**

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    x=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)

    if [ "$2" == "BRTUP" ]
      then
        x=$(echo $x+490 | bc)
        echo $x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
    fi

    if [ "$2" == "BRTDN" ]
      then
        x=$(echo $x-490 | bc)
        echo $x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
    fi
   ```

   Make the script executable with `chmod +x /etc/acpi/intel-backlight.sh`.